# Event is not firing while created a table from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

First, let me show you its design
[image]

Here on the click of the Add Section button, I have to create an HTML table where the first row is the header.

### Page.ascx.cs

```
<table id="tableContainer">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <th style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">Name</th>
                                                                <th style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">Question</th>
                                                                <th style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">TotalTime</th>
                                                                <th style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">Action</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody id="tbltbody" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                                                        </tbody>

                                                    </table>
```

Now on the click of the button,

```
function createTable() {
    debugger;
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td1 = document.createElement('td');

    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    var td3 = document.createElement('td');
    var td4 = document.createElement('td');

    let sectionName = document.getElementById('txtSectionName');
    let sectionTotQuest = document.getElementById('txtSectionTotQuestion');
    let sectionTotMin = document.getElementById('txtSectionMinutes');

    var text1 = document.createTextNode(sectionName.value);
    var text2 = document.createTextNode(sectionTotQuest.value);
    var text3 = document.createTextNode(sectionTotMin.value);

    const link = document.createElement('a');
    // add a classs
    link.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';
    // icon html
    link.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>';

    td1.appendChild(text1);
    td2.appendChild(text2);
    td3.appendChild(text3);
    td4.appendChild(link);

    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    tr.appendChild(td3);
    tr.appendChild(td4);

    //tblContainer.appendChild(tr);

    document.querySelector('#tbltbody').appendChild(tr);
    // cleanup
    sectionName.value = ""; sectionTotMin.value = ""; sectionTotQuest.value = "";
    return false;
}
```

and while click on the x button,

```
tblContainer.addEventListener('click', removeTask);

// remove Task
function removeTask(e) {
    debugger;
    if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('delete-item')) {
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    }
}
```

Now upto this point, every thing is working perfectly . Now my job is to save those data into database and later its need to be displayed on page..

Now, rendering as a table from code behind,

```
foreach (DataRow dr in drs)
                        {
                            sb.Append("<tr>");
                            sb.Append("<td>" + dr["section_name"] + "</td>");
                            sb.Append("<td>" + dr["total_section_question"] + "</td>");
                            sb.Append("<td>" + dr["total_section_time_mint"] + "</td>");
                            sb.Append("<td><a class='delete-item secondary-content'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></a></td>");
                            sb.Append("</tr>");
                            tbltbody.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
                        }
```

Now everything is rendering as expected but the delete button's (X) click event is not working (it does not hit the breakpoint on removeTask() function)...Why? How to resolve that?

Comment: I can highly recommend to use some javascript framework like vue or react for that.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
sb.Append("<td><a class='delete-item secondary-content'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></a></td>");
```

to

```
sb.Append("<td><a onclick='removeTask(this)' class='delete-item secondary-content'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></a></td>");
```

Now it will trigger the `removeTask(e)` event.

Comment: Sir, it's now firing that event but,e.target is showing as ""  and that is why I am getting  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at removeTask

Comment: okay then repalce `a` tag with `button` with `type="button"`, I am sure it would work for you.